# How to sort table that are inserted using insertRow()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to sort data in table that are being added using insertRow()? i tried sorting method like jquery but its not working. i believe that its because my data are not hardcoded but being inserted using insertRow(). i wanted to sort based on user's dropdown menu

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <label for="userID">User ID</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" readonly="true" disabled="true">
            <input type="text" id="userName" name="username" placeholder="UserName">
            <input type="text" id="userOccupation" name="userOccupation" placeholder="UserOccupation">
            <button type="button" onclick=addData()>Add</button>
        </form>
        <text>Sort by:</text>
        <select value="Sort based on:" id="occupationDropdown" onchange="sortSelect(this.value);">
            <option value='1'>UserID</option>
            <option value='2'>UserName</option>
            <option value='3'>UserOccupation</option>                
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id="table" border="1px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="userID">User ID</th>
                    <th id="userName">User Name</th>
                    <th id="userOccupation">User Occupation</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my javascript:-

```
    //variable for increment the user id
var seq = 0;
seq++;
document.getElementById("userID").value = seq;
//function to add new data to table
function addData(){
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var userid = document.getElementById("userID").value;
    var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var userOccupation = document.getElementById("userOccupation").value;
    var row = table.insertRow(seq);
    //insert data accordingly to their column
    var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var col3 = row.insertCell(2);
    col1.innerHTML = userid;
    col2.innerHTML = userName;
    col3.innerHTML = userOccupation;
    //clearing text input after add new data
    document.getElementById("userID").value = "";
    document.getElementById("userName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("userOccupation").value = "";
    //increment the user id
    seq = seq + 1;
    document.getElementById("userID").value = seq;
}

function sortSelect(value){
    // The following code should sort the table.
    var tbody = $('#table').find('tbody');
    tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    }).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some minor changes to your code. Actually, you do not need jquery

```js
const columns = ["userID", "userName", "userOccupation"];
let seq = 1;
let sortOrder = 1;

const mapSortName = {
  1: "userID",
  2: "userName",
  3: "userOccupation"
}

document.getElementById("userID").value = seq;
//function to add new data to table
const addData = () => {
  const tbody = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  const userId = document.getElementById("userID").value;
  const userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  const occuption = document.getElementById("userOccupation").value;

  //insert data accordingly to their column
  const html = `<tr><td>${userId}</td><td>${userName}</td><td>${occuption}</td></tr>`;
  tbody.innerHTML += html;

  //clearing text input after add new data
  columns.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).value = "");
  //increment the user id
  seq++;
  document.getElementById("userID").value = seq;
  sortSelect(sortOrder);
}

const sortSelect = (value) => {
  sortOrder = value;
  const orderby = mapSortName[value]

  // The following code should sort the table.
  const tbody = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  const data = [...tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")].map(row => {
    const colValues = [...row.getElementsByTagName("td")].map(td => td.innerText);
    return columns.reduce((a, c, i) => {
      a[c] = colValues[i];
      return a;
    }, {});
  });

  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (orderby !== "userID") {
      return a[orderby] > b[orderby] ? 1 : -1;
    }
    num_a = parseInt(a[orderby], 10);
    num_b = parseInt(b[orderby], 10);
    return num_a > num_b ? 1 : -1;
  });
  tbody.innerHTML = data.map(row => {
    return `<tr><td>${row.userID}</td><td>${row.userName}</td><td>${row.userOccupation}</td></tr>`;
  }).join("");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label for="userID">User ID</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" readonly="true" disabled="true">
      <input type="text" id="userName" name="username" placeholder="UserName">
      <input type="text" id="userOccupation" name="userOccupation" placeholder="UserOccupation">
      <button type="button" onclick=addData()>Add</button>
    </form>
    <text>Sort by:</text>
    <select value="Sort based on:" id="occupationDropdown" onchange="sortSelect(this.value);">
      <option value='1'>UserID</option>
      <option value='2'>UserName</option>
      <option value='3'>UserOccupation</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="table" border="1px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="userID">User ID</th>
          <th id="userName">User Name</th>
          <th id="userOccupation">User Occupation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the change event of the `<select>` so it calls your sort function

After inserting the row try:

```
$('#occupationDropdown')[0].onchange()
```